# How to reduce box size of seaborn box plot and make figure adapt to the new box sizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I created the figure below with the code shown below the image. I'd like the boxes to be thinner in the horizontal direction and the entire figure to adapt to the new box sizes. How can I do that?

I know that I can change the the width of the boxes with `sns.boxplot(data=df,width=someScalingFactor)`, but this creates a space between the boxes in horizontal direction and this is not what I want.

[image]

```py
def plotBoxPlotDataMAE(self,data,figName):        
    df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
    df = df.rename(columns={0:'Joint 1',1:'Joint 2',2:'Joint 3',3:'Average'})
    f = plt.figure(figName,figsize=[5.3,6])
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    obj = sns.boxplot(data=df)
    obj.set_ylabel(ylabel='Mean Absolute Angle Error [°]',fontsize=13)
    plt.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',labelleft='on',labelright='on')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
```

Ultimately I want the figure to be thinner because the boxes being large doesn't add information to the plot and I don't have much space in the document where I'd like to use them.

Comment: Why not just make a thinner figure by setting a thinner `figsize` when you call `plt.figure`?

Comment: If I make the `figsize` smaller, then the label of the y-axis will disappear.

Comment: If you change the figsize and some parts become invisible, you can adjust the border spacing with something like [`plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html). Or [`plt.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the boxes are determined based on the size of the axes, which are dependent on the size of the figure. So to get a thinner figure with thinner boxes, you need to change the figure size.

As you noted, that creates problem with the axes and tick labels, but that's easily taken care of using `tight_layout()` as pointed out by @JohanC.

full code:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=[2,6])
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
sns.boxplot(data=df, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel='Mean Absolute Angle Error [°]',fontsize=13)
plt.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',labelleft='on',labelright='on')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
f.tight_layout()
```

[image]